# mod_rewrite issues transferring subdomain to path for rewriting later in the ruleset

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to edit my `.htaccess` file to add a subdomain redirect to my `mod_rewrite` rules.

Currently I am redirecting http://www.example.com to http://example.com and then translating the path that follows to call some scripts as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/(option1|option2)/?$ /?id=$1&option=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/?$ /?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+)/([^/]+) /api.php?command=$1&options=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+) /api.php?command=$1 [L]
```

The above all seems to work fine and has been for a couple of years.

I now want to add a new rule to redirect http://api.example.com to http://example.com/api and then have the same `^api/` rules as above applied.

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ api/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/(option1|option2)/?$ /?id=$1&option=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/?$ /?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+)/([^/]+) /api.php?command=$1&options=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+) /api.php?command=$1 [L]
```

in the hope that this would first of all add `api/` to the start of the path followed by the remainder of the URL path, then use the original rewrite rules to translate the api parameters into the `api.php` arguments as the rules have been doing up to now.

However if I navigate to http://api.example.com/myCommand/myOptions I get and error that `api.example.com/myCommand/myOptions was not found` so it seems that the `^api.` rewrite rules are not being run. My guess was that this was because api.example.com does not match the the second `RewriteCond`.

Next attempt was to allow www or api in the second RewriteCond as folows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ api/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|api)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/(option1|option2)/?$ /?id=$1&option=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/?$ /?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+)/([^/]+) /api.php?command=$1&options=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+) /api.php?command=$1 [L]
```

Now the rules appears to be being picked up in that the api is being removed from the hostname, but I am still getting the error `example.com/myCommand/myOptions was not found`.

Note that on my server I do not have a subdirectory called `id` but this does not throw an error the way `myCommand` appears to be.

Note also that the last example `.htaccess` does not seem to be adding the `api/` to the start of the path either, which could account for the 'not found' error - `myCommand` doesn't actually exist and the `.htaccess` is not rewiting for `myCommand` so this seems to be a legitimate error, BUT why is `.htaccess` not adding the `api/` so that it does get rewritten?

It seems that the problem stems from the fact the `api/` is not being correctly added to the start of the path by

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ api/$1
```

but I cannot figure out why.

But then, am I thinking things through correctly in thnking that the rules will be processed in sequence and that once the `api/` is inserted coectly, the later rules will rewrite that part of the path correctly as well?

Finally, as an aside, is it possible to use relative protocols in `mod_rewrite` rules? ie can I omit the `http` from the `RewriteRule` to enable `http` and `https` rewrites automatically?

-FM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!api[/.])(.*)$ api/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]+)/(option1|option2)/?$ /?id=$1&option=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^id/([^/.]*)/?$ /?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+)/([^/]+) /api.php?command=$1&options=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z\d]+) /api.php?command=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That's got me closer, though now if I navigate to `example.com/first/second` the rewritten URL appears in the address bar as `example.com/api/first/second/second` i.e. the second level path is repeated twice.. (I also don't really understand how that example works, what is the (?!api/) doing? Is it making sure that the path doesn't already start with api/?

Comment: No more duplicating the second parameter with those changes, but not actually doing the rewrite either - I still have the api. in the domain and the api/ isn't being added to the path now.

Comment: It doesn't give a 404, but to me it look like the second RewriteCond in you code is looking for a hostname starting with www. before applying the following rules - so the rewrites won't be applied. It also looks like the $1 back ref is being applied at the hostname and the path in the first RewriteRule after the second RewriteCond.

Comment: 2nd rewrite rule is same as in your question and that is only for removing `www` from main domain. `http://api.example.com/myCommand/myOptions` should remain unchanged in browser but it should load `http://api.example.com/api.php? command=myCommand&options=myOptions` internally.

Comment: Doh! It looks like it was pretty much working right from the start - I was fooling myself because the hostname isn't changing and so there isn't a reload and/or address bar change. Looking at my api.php logs I can see that the correct params are being passed on.

Comment: An oddity I have found in those api.php logs, though, is that the request for api.example.com/favicon.ico is also being passed to my api.php script... that's an overhead I could do without...

Comment: I think I actually need to explicitly exclude it from the last `^api/` rule as that is the only place is is being picked up. Other file and directory cases - when not on the api subdomain - are legitimate so I wouldn't want to affect those. Looking at the regex now...

Comment: A bit more thinking and you are right.. blocking all files and directories when the hostname is api. is probably just what I need. Answer accepted. Thanks.